# Regular expression splitting a optional group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have tried to set up a regular expression in JavaScript that would accept a string like `12:13:14.15` (at max) but when doing just `12:13`, it will split the first match `(12)` into two matches.

I've been at this for some time now and I can't figure out what is causing this.

This is the expression I'm using:

```
^(\d+)?:?(\d+):(\d+).?(\d+)?$
```

From what I've tried, it supposed to be set up like this:

- `(XX:)XX:XX(.XX)` , where () is optional.

As I mentioned above, filling the whole thing out works and everything gets into their respective matches. But leaving out the first optional part causes it to split the first match into two matches.

---

For example:

The full string is `54:13.15`. It will split `54` into one match with `5` and one match with `4`. What I want it to do is to split `54`, `13`, `15` into groups. It should split by every `:` and `.`.

Mind you, this example is **WITHOUT** the optional part. With the optional part included, it will split correctly.

I also need to go with regular expressions because I need to restrict the number of splits it can do. I don't want it to be able to have multiple `.` splits or like 10 `:` splits.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit the question and add an example of what you're starting with and what you want in the end? This is really not clear: `The full string is 54:13.15. It will split '12' into one match with '5' and one match with '4'.` Where did '12' come from? Are you just trying to split on `:`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry, I missed that! I first intended to write 12 but changed it to 54 to make it a bit more clear but forgot to change 12 there. I've also expanded on the example.

Comment: Are you after [^(\d+)?:?(\d+)?:(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$](https://regex101.com/r/4KvuNe/1) ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness That actually did the trick. It just moves one of the matches around but I could work with that.

Comment: [Is this better](https://regex101.com/r/4KvuNe/2) ? Let me know, still a bit unclear what you are after.

Comment: yeh you need to explain less and be specific. provide some examples of outcome you want and you dont.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness The old one actually worked better because it left the millisecond in group 4. What I meant with a match moving around is that the minute could take the first place (hour place) but that is an easy check on my part. So I would mark your previous comment as an answer as it fixed what I wanted.

Comment: @Hertzole I think I understand what you were trying to do now. I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression:

[^(\d+)?:?(\d+)?:(\d+).?(\d+)?$](https://regex101.com/r/4KvuNe/1)

```js
var timestamp = '12:13:14.15'
var re = /^(\d+)?:?(\d+)?:(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$/g

matches = re.exec(timestamp)
ms = matches[4]
console.log(ms)

var timestamp = '54:13.20'
var re = /^(\d+)?:?(\d+)?:(\d+)\.?(\d+)?$/g

matches = re.exec(timestamp)
ms = matches[4]
console.log(ms)
```

Comment: You are welcome, the tricky part was figuring out what the real question was :P

Comment: I've noted that and will do my best to improve until next time!

Comment: All good, that's the right mentality. I edited your question to make it a bit more readable btw.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can just match the delimiters that you want to split on. You don't need to capture the rest. Fore example:

```js
let st = '54:13.15'
// split on : and .
console.log(st.split(/[:.]/))

st = '12:13:14.15'
console.log(st.split(/[:.]/))

st = '12:13:14'
console.log(st.split(/[:.]/))
```

Comment: While this could work, I'm making it more complicated because I need to know which is which. And while I am writing this I could probably do the same by checking if the string contains a '.' and that probably means the last element in the array is the milliseconds. But a regex also gives me the power to not allow too many splits either and the matches stay in place.

Comment: @Hertzole Those constraints would be excellent details for the question.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm sorry for not including it. So many details to include when asking!